# Hosting angular part of asp.net boilerplate in "wwwroot" folder of the API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I was trying out asp.net boilerplate and and opted for the solution with separate angular / core projects ... But since my cheap web hosting allows only one app I've been trying to copy content from angular dist inside the wwwroot of the api where swagger is hosted but the app/AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll return either 404 or 200 but no content which results in Error parsing JSON...

BTW: I turned off SSL/https for testing purposes...

Is there some guide how to set up the core part to host angular dist files inside the wwwroot?

I tried:

- change lunchSettings.json
- useStaticFiles()...
- useDefaultFiles() ...
- route rewrite etc ...
- all the recommended stuff

UPDATE:
After following the suggested link ([How do I add an Angular project to an exisiting .NET Core Web API project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62902419/how-do-i-add-an-angular-project-to-an-exisiting-net-core-web-api-project)), I modified the necessary part to serve the dist folder locally (without 4200 part) to simulate server environment which would mean I only need app.UseStaticFiles and no part of app.UseSpa as I want to serve only the already generated stuff from dist folder...

```
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            // app.UseSpa(spa =>{ ... }); // Not needed
```

I still get an error but this time no content
[image]

So the question remains how to serve the angular static files from dist folder together with core API locally and later remotely (should be almost the same)?
Can they work on the same port etc .. do we need some magic :D

UPDATE 2: By using just these settings...

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory){
    ...
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    ...
}
```

swagger is back and working again,
but I need to navigate manually to a index.html which now shows login page in its full glory without any errors finishing initial requests that were not possible before.

But the login doesn't work... a few errors pop up and a 400 is returned. Somehow I doubt the login is bad as its remained unchanged since the project generation from asp.net boilerplate.

the few errors look like this
[image]

And I think I need url rewriting  ... because I need to target {baseUrl}/index.html to load the login page which redirects to {baseUrl}/account/login that can not be refreshed or manually navigated to using the address bar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62902419/how-do-i-add-an-angular-project-to-an-exisiting-net-core-web-api-project

Comment: @HusseinBeygi tried that one already... the difference being that I want in my development  environment to serve the files from dist too (not serving on 4200 port). I want to simulate the conditions from the hosting...

So this still doesnt serve it as I wanted (except my swagger is not working any more too) and the error regarding  the AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll is no longer 404 but no response as updated in the question ....

Comment: You can't serve two applications on the same port.