# How to serve an Angular application from an ASP.NET Core Web API application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have 2 different Git repositories, one is an Angular application, the other is an ASP.NET Core web API application.

How to serve an compiled Angular application (dist) from an ASP.NET Core web API application?

StaticFiles middleware simply serves files and does not understand Angular routing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add an Angular project to an exisiting .NET Core Web API project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62902419/how-do-i-add-an-angular-project-to-an-exisiting-net-core-web-api-project)

Comment: @possum No, because I don't want to move angular source files to ASP.NET Core application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the compiled files in your deployment and in your middleware pipeline, include

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

at the end. Any request not matched by the API will serve the angular index.html and from there Angular Routing can take over.